# How To Process A Sentence In Special Format In PLSQL

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql

I would like to decode the content of csv in PLSQL.

The content of the csv as following.

`"HEADER_ROW1_COL1,WITH_COMMA",HEADER_ROW1_COL2,my darling's ccc
DATA_ROW2_COL1,DATA_ROW2_COL2
DATA_ROW3_COL1,DATA_ROW3_COL2`

[image: cle]

CSV will split the column with a comma. If the cell contains a comma, CSV will enclosed the content of the cell with double quotes.

Threfore, if I want to read the content of the Excel file, I need to follow the steps as following

1. Read the content of the CSV by line
2. Split the text with comma
3. If the comma is enclosed by two double quotes, ignore the comma

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to do this in PL/SQL? As opposed to say SQL\*Loader or an external table? Or using a tool like Oracle SQL Developer?